# Interspaces between nodes in Treeview wpf

Tags: wpf

I can't cope with set interspaces between nodes in Treeview wpf.

I manipulate padding and gives me in result interspaces between main nodes, but not between child nodes.

Is there any way to get rid of this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can also set the padding and margins on your child nodes:

- If you are using a HierarchicalDataTemplate, just set eg Margin="-1" in your outermost element in the template.
- If you are using some other technique, please post details on how your TreeView is being constructed.